# Linking the color of one mesh to a second mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, vertex-colors

[image: Uncolored sphere]

[image: Varying colored tubes]

I have a series of tubes that were inputted as VRMLs with varying colors. I have made a path out of them and have the sphere following the tubes. I want to link the color of the sphere to be the same as the tube while the sphere is traveling in time over the tubes. How can I link the colors? I also want the sphere to glow with the color of the tube.

Comment: With textures it is not too hard, just make the mapping based off of an object, and put the same material on the sphere. As is, I'm not sure . . .

Comment: What defines the color of the tubes?

Comment: @PGmath His nodes have an *Attribute* node with a Col value. I would assume that it is what is influencing the color.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I currently have the material on the sphere the same as the tubes. Can you explain more on how to map the sphere with the object being the tube or provide a link for mapping based on an object?

Comment: @PGmath NoviceInDisguise is correct. I am using an Attribute node which contains the tubes coloring based on settings from an external program.

Comment: @rwinfree Are the colors generated by some math formula or algorithim?  Also, would it be possible to use a texture for the colors instead of vertex colors?

Comment: @PGmath They are generated by another program and represent a variable (they are calculated by a math formula). I am not sure how VRMLs work but looking at the file it is a list of points and colors. 
The color would need to change each frame and I didn't use a texture to get the colors. I am unsure if I could use a texture since the colors are stored as an attribute of the tubes.

Comment: Is the math formula accessible?  If so, what are the variables that determine the color?  I could conceivably recreate the formula in cycles nodes, or with my limited (but expanding) knowledge of OSL, and package it in a node group for you.

Comment: @PGmath I think I have made this sound too complicated. The colors represent velocity but how they were calculated is through proprietary work. The color data is stored in the VRML format and when I add the "Input" of "Attribute" it finds the colors specified at each face and adds those to the tubes. I am not sure how Blender reads the file in and places the colors.

Comment: Hmm... The problem here is that vertex colors aren't that accessible, basically just from the node editor and only by the object which has the colors and they give no vector (location) information.  I will continue trying to think of a way do it though!

Comment: I have figured out a way that works fairly well (mostly), I don't have time to post an answer now but sometime tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to do this using translucency and some node tricks to make the tube emit light when it is under the ball, it isn't perfect but it works fairly well.

First give the ball a pure white *transparent* shader mixed with a *translucent* shader based on the *is camera ray* output of the *light path* node:
[image]
This will make the ball invisible to everything but the camera, this isn't necessary but will reduce noise, artifacts, and rendering time.

Next give the tubes a *diffuse* shader mixed with an *emission* shader (with a very high strength) based on the *is transmission ray* output of the *light path* node and plug the vertex colors into both the diffuse and emission shaders:
[image]
This will make the tube emit light when a ray is traveling through an object (such as a translucent object), but the tube will look like normal (the diffuse shader) elsewhere.

#### This is the result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This was a very creative idea! It worked well enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

A new [2.74 feature](https://developer.blender.org/rBdf07a25) allows controlling texture mapping by object, which may also be a choice:

- Use **Object** coordinate for mapping, an empty object as the coordinate controller;
- Assign the same material to both tube and sphere.

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** Since this is a new feature that will be officially released with the coming 2.74 version, you may have to compile your own build, or download any of the daily builds from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

Comment: Very nice! Once this makes it into the official build, this could be great!

Comment: Awesome!  I have been wanting that for sooo long!  The problem for this application though is that the tube colors are defined by vertex colors, and can't really be put into a color ramp.