# Coupling particles textures and position

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, particles, force-fields

I am generating a set of particles that follow a streamline and I would like the particles to change color according to their position along the line. The tricky part is that the streamline has a image texture shader and I would like the particles to be matching the texture.
[image]

Is there a simple way to do so?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this [streamline] have arbitrary curve, or is a straight line segment?  Could it be a tangled knot?  Perhaps you can show an example image with color.  Will the sphere be one single color or more than one color?

Comment: The particles are following a bezier curve. I duplicated the curve into a solid mesh in order to texture it. What I would like is to have the particles color matching the textures: the particles should be red when they are above a red segment of the streamline etc.

Comment: So that is a solid color for each sphere, No stripes?

Comment: Actually it can be striped, when located over a striped region. The particles are moving along the line, so they are supposed to change color (based on their position)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Particles change color based on age / lifetime. I have left in transparency.  You can determine if position corresponds to that number.

Comment: Smart! That could work, thanks! I found some extra info here as well:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23183/linking-the-color-of-one-mesh-to-a-second-mesh
Thanks again for your help :)